# Progress 4gl- internal procedure name

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

this seems simple to me, but i can not find the proper attribute.  for error reporting purposes, i'd like to know the name of the internal procedure i'm in.

Here is the simplest of examples:

Run Test.

Procedure Test.

/* how can i display the procedure name 'test' here? */

End Procedure.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at `PROGRAM-NAME()` function.

As per the documentation:

> If the procedure you reference is an internal procedure, then PROGRAM-NAME returns a string with the following form:
>       "`internal-procedure-name source-file-name`"

For the example you gave:

```
Run Test.

Procedure Test.
     message PROGRAM-NAME(1).
End Procedure.
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I had tried this but didn't notice it was returning a list, i only saw the actual program path/name in the message.  Thank you!